# Упростить код php. 2 запроса 2 цикла в один

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$this->query("SELECT");             
while($r = $this->get_row())        
   $rw[$r['id']]['procent'] = $r['procent'];
            
$this->query("SELECT");             
while($r = $this->get_row())        
   $rw[$r['id']]['save'] = 'trues';
```

В некоторых случаях, необходимо собрать из 2 и более таблиц и соотнести все к одному ключу. В данном примере необходимо выбрать процент из первой и узнать о наличии записи из второй. Затем взять все новости из таблицы и так же соотнести по ключю.

Именно эти два процесса необходимо выполнять в том случаи когда пользователь идентифицирован.

Вопрос. Возможно сразу выполнить 2 запроса в две таблицы без пересечения и привязки друг к другу.То есть есть массив c id записями которые необходимо вытащить и из первой и из второй. А затем результат в один цикл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

обычно такие вещи выполняются с помощью связывания таблиц посредством `JOIN` операторов.

Но поскольку вы пишите, что связывать таблицы вам не надо, и если уж есть очень большое желание сделать это одним запросом и циклом обработки, то можно решить следующим образом

```
 SELECT id, 'procent' as field, procent FROM t1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, 'save' as field, 1 FROM t2
```

целесообразность этого сомнительна, особенно если данные логически не шибко связаны. Если вы хотите избежать дублирования пхп код для выборки, то лучше унифицируйте его в виде функций, а не переноса логики в sql

Comment: Одну выборку к обоим запросам возможно применить?